# Selenium xpath links with Python firefox driver not clicking

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

I need help with said subject. I am attaching a screenshot where I am stuck after login and several clicks into the webpage. Both chromedriver and gekodriver, same issue.

What I am after is the "Launch" button shown in the image. The highlighted elements is shown in the image in blue and the xpath is pretty simple:
    "r'//*[@id="HME-8-widget_launch_button"]'".

I tried the following:

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox();
...
Launch = r'//*[@id="HME-8-widget_launch_button"]'
link = driver.find_element_by_xpath(Launch)
act.move_to_element(link)
act.click()
act.perform()
```

The simpler

```
link.click()
```

does not work either.

What am I missing?
[image: screenshot]
Thanks,

Alvin

Comment: please use the snippet tool via [edit] to insert html rather than paste an image.

Comment: any error or something ?

Comment: @ALvinDas [Don't do this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/361474/should-we-display-a-warning-when-users-include-images/361481#361481). Please read why a [screenshot of HTML or code or error is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Consider updating the Question with formatted text based relevant HTML, code trials and error stack trace.

Comment: @DerbanjanB do you know of any way to copy the teext of HTML as pictured in the Chrome dev console.  I can't highlight and copy the whole thing, I can only copy line by line, which is too tedious for the effort.  I wonder if others have the same problem and that's why the selenium tag often see questions with pictures like this.

Comment: Can you please check that is there any iframe present in the html structure above the element you want to click ?

Answer (score 0):

Your xPath stored in `Launch` doesn't seem right.  First of all, if I understand the usage of `r'xpath'` correctly, it makes it so that backslash doesn't escape characters.  I'm guessing you have `act` defined as an ActionChains in which case the rest of your code should work, but I'm going to suggest either

```
xpath = "//*[@id='HME-8-widget_launch_button']"
link = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath)
link.click()
```

if you want to reuse that element, or if you don't need to reuse it and just want to click it, you can simply do

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='HME-8-widget_launch_button']").click()
```

Edit to add:

WAIT.. I assume you are trying to click on the highlighted element in your image correct?  on the third line of your image there is another element with `id='HME-8-widget_launch_button` and that one would be found first.  I can't say for sure without seeing your full HTML, but you could maybe use the class of that button to select your element.  Try the following and let me know if it works:

```
link = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button.hm-button.k-button")
```

I can't test it but does that identify your element?

### Edit to hopefully fix root cause

Oh I think I know why that you cant click that. Looking at your screenshot, the element you are trying to click is right after a javascript execution. If you take a look at that javascript, it calls a function that makes a JQuery request that looks something like this:

```
JQuery(yourElement).closest('.hm-widget').show()
```

The JQuery documentation for `closest()` and `show()` [here](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) and [here](https://api.jquery.com/show/) respectively indicate that that `closest('.hm-widget')` will "begin with the current element" and go "up the DOM tree until it finds a match for the supplied selector".  From your screenshot I can see that the third div above the script tag has a class of `'hm-widget hc-button'` and I believe that is what `.show()` is targeting and therefore that div is being displayed, covering up your div and making it unclickable.

Two suggestions to try: try just clicking on that div and see if it clicks the button.   I'm sure you can figure that out yourself bug for example:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div.hm-widget.hc-button').click()
```

Or use whatever selector you prefer.  I assume the user can click on this button even after the `<script>` tag executes, which makes me think the above could work.

If that doesn't work, I wonder what happens if you try to combat the site's jQuery using your own jQuery in `driver.execute_javascript`.  One thing you could do is try to use jQuery's `detach` function to simply remove the offending javascript that I noted.  I think the can be accomplished by the following:

```
css = "div.hm-widget-element > script"
scripts = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(css)
```

This store an array of (at least) two `scripts` from your image, so `scripts[0]` will identify the script above your highlighted element.  The following should remove that  tag from the DOM so you can (hopefully) click the button unimpeded.

```
driver.execute_script('Arguments[0].remove()', scripts[0])
```

If THIS doesn't work, one last thing would be to try to remove the script that *follows* your highlighted element.  I'm not entirely sure what that one does but it seems to do something with your target element.

```
driver.execute_script('Arguments[0].remove', scripts[1])
```

If you take this approach, I would add the javascript execution just after the page has loaded and before you take any actions in the browser.

Again, I can't test it so let me know how this goes.

Comment: @CPeck I was using a function and passing in the raw string, which works for all the links up to this point. But I did try your method, nothing happens, and no error output. The entire code is in a try-exception block and no errors are generated. It just won't click and bring up the next page.

Comment: See the edit I have added to the bottom of my answer and let me know if that helps.

Again, seeing the full HTML or getting a link to the page in question would be very helpful.

Comment: @CPeck Appreciate your input: I tried both:    *link = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button#HME-8-widget_launch_button")* and *link = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='HME-8-widget_launch_button']")*. I print the contents of *link* and they identify the same element, supposedly the *Launch* button highlighted in the image in blue. It just won't click.

Comment: I think I figured out why the click wasn't working--see the latest edit to my answer for an explanation and some possible solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this

```
launchXpath = "//button[@id='HME-8-widget_launch_button']"
launchBtn = driver.find_element_by_xpath(launchXpath )
launchBtn.click()
```

Suggestion: You can also use `id` instead of `xpath`.

Comment: I did try ID also, same issue...where nothing happens.

Comment: I tried that. All leads to the same element, when I print. But it won't click